# Why can't attach attachments by mail with sendgrid?

Tags: c#, email, attachment, sendgrid

When I try to send an email with attachments located in a google drive or repository route, it only sends the email but without the files.

I try to download the file in bytes and then send it as an attachment

The code used is the following

```
List<Attachment> files = new List<Attachment>
{  
   new Attachment()
   {
      Content = "BwdW",
      Type = "image/png",
      Filename = Server.MapPath("~/Content/IMG/EmailHeader.png"),
      Disposition = "inline",
      ContentId = "EmailHeader"
   } 
};
```

This is the method:

```
 public Boolean EnvioCorreo_Copias_Archivos(string cuerpo, string asunto, string correoEmisor, List<EmailAddress> correoReceptor,
                                               List<Attachment> Archivos)
    {
        try
        {
            var clientSendGrid = new SendGridClient("Key_Sendgrid");
            var from = new EmailAddress(correoEmisor, "Alias"); 
            List<EmailAddress> tos = correoReceptor;

            var body = cuerpo; 
            var subject = asunto;
            var plainTextContent = "";
            var htmlContent = body;
            var showAllRecipients = true;

            var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmailToMultipleRecipients(from, tos, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent, showAllRecipients); 
            msg.AddAttachments(Archivos); 
            clientSendGrid.SendEmailAsync(msg).Wait(); 
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the part where you attach the file(s) to the e-mail and send it?

Comment: Hi, AsheraH, I already put the complete method to send emails.

Comment: You created the attachment but you never added it to the email programmatically. You are missing the line that adds `files` to the email.

Comment: @Renan, **List<Attachment> Archivos**, is the parameter where files come in

Comment: @Renan it is only a reultilizable method

Comment: `catch...return false` is a bad way of doing exception handling. If you wouldn't have ignored the exception, its error message would probably have helped you more than asking here on SO.

Comment: Hello, the mail was sent correctly, the problem is that the attachment does not send it; @Uwe Keim

Comment: `Disposition = "inline"` = no attachment

Comment: Does someone have an example of how to send attachments with sendgrid? (images, pdf, etc) dynamically

Answer (score 2):

Personaly I am using this for a single email attachment:

```
var Message = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(AttachmentPath);
var File = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
Message.AddAttachment(FileName, File);
APIResponse = await client.SendEmailAsync(Message).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: This is the best solution to read in the right way a file. Some times you find also this: `byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(File.ReadAllText(filePath));` but will not read in the right way every file...

Answer (score 0):

I just confirmed this works with SendGrid, attachment worked fine:

```
var msg = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
{
  Subject = "attachment test", 
  IsBodyHtml = true, 
  Body = "this is the body"
};

var attachment = new Attachment(attachmentPath);
msg.Attachments.Add(attachment);

using (var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.sendgrid.net"))
{
  client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
  client.EnableSsl = true;
  client.Port = 587;
  client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("key","password");

  await client.SendMailAsync(msg);
}
```